The chain rule for partial derivatives
My goal is to understand a statement about partial derivatives made in the appendix of a textbook about manifolds. From the book:

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tilde{U}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be open subsets, and let $x = (x^1, ..., x^n)$ denote the standard coordinates on $U$ and $y = (y^1, ..., y^m)$ those on $\tilde{U}$... A composition of $C^1$ functions $F:U\rightarrow \tilde{U}$ and $G:\tilde{U}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is again of class $C^1$, with partial derivatives given by
$$ \frac{\partial (G^i \circ F)}{\partial x^j}(x) 
= \sum_{k =1}^m \frac{\partial G^i}{\partial y^k}\left(F(x)\right) \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^j}(x).\tag{1}$$

I want to justify the last equation for myself.
I think I may be confused by the different roles played by $y^k$ and $F^k$. I believe $y^k$ is the $k$-th coordinate function on $\tilde{U}$ and $F^k = y^k \circ F$.
Here's my attempt at a proof. Let $e_j$ be the $j$-th standard basis vector in $U$. Starting with the LHS of the equation,
$$\frac{\partial (G^i \circ F)}{\partial x^j}(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{G^i\circ F(x + h e_j) - G^i \circ F(x)}{h}.$$
To get something resembling the RHS of \eqref{1}, I think I need to multiply by 1 in the following way:
$$\frac{\partial (G^i \circ F)}{\partial x^j}(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{G^i\circ F(x + h e_j) - G^i \circ F(x)}{h} \frac{\sum_k F^k(x + h e_j) - F^k(x)}{\sum_k F^k(x + h e_j) - F^k(x)}
= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{G^i\circ F(x + h e_j) - G^i \circ F(x)}{\sum_k F^k(x + h e_j) - F^k(x)} \frac{\sum_k F^k(x + h e_j) - F^k(x)}{h}.$$
The last factor on the right looks similar to the last factor I need in \eqref{1}:
$$\frac{\sum_k F^k(x + h e_j) - F^k(x)}{h} = \sum_k \frac{\partial F^k}{\partial x^j}(x).$$
But where does the $y^k$ come from in $\frac{\partial G^i}{\partial y^k}$ found in \eqref{1}?
Thanks in advance for any help in clearing up my confusion!
